# Actualizar los datos de un array cuando se hace clic afuera del input

Tags: javascript, html5, array, json

Cordial saludo estoy elaborando un proyecto en Laravel donde realizo una actualización de datos en una tabla dinámicamente ,estos datos son un array que se crear al seleccionar un ítem y la función que realizo es que al dar clic en el botón verde me actualiza los datos ingresados en el array
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero un requerimiento que me han solicitado es que no este el botón verde, que al ingresar el dato en el input y dar el clic fuera del input se actualice automáticamente.
Para actualizar mis datos lo hago de esta manera, Esta es mi tabla

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <th style="font-size: 11.7px;">Item</th>
      <th style="font-size: 11.7px;">Eliminar</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach ($cart as $servicio)
   <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 11.7px;">
         <input type="text" 
                class="form-con-lg" 
                value="{{$servicio->n_item}}" 
                id="servicio_{{$servicio->id}}">
         <a class="btn-update-item btn btn-success" 
            data-href="{{ route('servicio_update',$servicio->id)}}" 
            data-id="{{$servicio->id}}">
            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="{{ route('coti_delete' ,$servicio->id )}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
</table>
```

y este es mi script donde paso los datos para actualizar mi array

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-update-item").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var href = $(this).data('href');
            var n_item = $("#servicio_" + id).val();
            swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
            window.location.href = href  + "/" + n_item;
        });
    });
</script>
```

y mi controlador donde actualizo mi array

```html
//UPADTE
    public function update(Servicios $servicios,$n_item){
        $cart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart[$servicios->id]->n_item = $n_item;
        Session::put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('coti_show');
    }
```

y mi route

```html
 Route::get('/servicios/update/{servicios}/{n_item?}', 'Admin\CotizacionController@update')->name('servicio_update');
```

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer que al ingresar el dato en el input y dar el clic fuera del input se actualice automáticamente, agradezco sus ayudas

Comment: Buen día, ¿Sería posible utilizar livewire en tu proyecto? Con livewire se puede hacer muy fácil

Comment: no es usado livewire pero me podrías decir como hacerlo te lo agradecería

Comment: Sería muy difícil explicar como utilizar livewire en un comentario o una respuesta pero el sitio web está [aquí](https://laravel-livewire.com/)  Lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar el script cada vez que alguno de los campos numéricos cambie utilizando `$(id).on("change", funcion{});`

Comment: ok revisare agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Veo que usas `jQuery`, por lo que una posible solución, es utilizar el evento `blur`, es decir, *cuando el elemento pierde el foco*, ya sea con un click fuera o con una tabulación.

```js
//Capturamos el value del input en el momento en que pierde el foco
$('#servicio_2054').on('blur', function(){
  let info = $('#servicio_2054').val();
  //Usamos el valor para lo que necesitemos
  console.log(`Se actualizó el input con esta información: ${info}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-con-lg" value="" id="servicio_2054">
```

En [este enlace](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) puedes encontrar la documentación oficial del evento.

Comment: lo probare gracias por tu ayuda